# Escape special characters from CString in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I would like to escape special characters from my CString variable. 
For eg: If the string contains "Te#st$ Va%lue", the out string should contain escape characters for the special characters('#', '$' and '%').

How should I do this in single function to escape all the special characters?

Comment: How is this a C# question?  Also, escape in what context(s)?

Comment: It this the `CString` from `MFC` you're talking about?

Comment: @BartvanNierop Yes CString from MFC. I need solution in C++.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically solved by implementing a fairly simple [transducer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer). I will try to provide more details later.